# Tawk.to integeration in react native?

Tags: react-native, tawk.to

Is it possible to integrate https://tawk.to in React Native? I have seen its web view but can't find anything regarding integration with react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per there feedback, they don't support React Native for now
http://feedback.tawk.to/forums/228427-feedback/suggestions/31163125-add-react-native-sdk

Answer (score 0):

```html
<WebView source={{ uri: YOUR_DIRECT_CHAT_LINK }} />
```

You can use the component for integration, but it must be said that this integration option means that you are using the option created for web pages. You may have problems with the functional part.